# Sticky list is not showing the scrollbar

Tags: css, sass

I have created a sticky list however after adding more content, no scroll bar appears and so the the list is being clipped. How do I fix this problem? I've added the styles as-well as the markup (only showing one list element however there's over 30 list items within the ul)

```css
.list {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 5rem;
  height: -webkit-max-content;
  height: -moz-max-content;
  height: max-content
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <h2>
    <button>
         <span>List</span>
        </button>
  </h2>
  <section class="list-links">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a>
              List
            </a>
      </li>
      <li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to make the header sticky and users scroll down the list but keep the title sticks, then codes should be like this:

```css
.list {
  height: 100px
  position: relative;
}
.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <h2 class="sticky">
    <button>
         <span>List</span>
        </button>
  </h2>
  <section class="list-links">
    <ul>
      <li>item</li>
      <li>item</li>
      <li>item</li>
      <li>item</li>
      <li>item</li>
      <li>item</li>
      <li>item</li>
      <li>item</li>
      <li>item</li>
      <li>item</li>
      <li>item</li>
      <li>item</li>
      <li>item</li>
      <li>item</li>
      <li>item</li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</div>
```

Note that you have `postition: sticky;` content inside of element that has `position'.